# What's the best practice for adding Android TV support to an existing smartphone / tablet app?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

The way I see it, there are a few options using Android Studio:

1. Add a new module for Android TV, and create a common module to share some of the code, but mainly re-write most of my code for Android TV.
2. Add one or more Android TV specific packages in my existing application code; add the Leanback manifest intent filter for the Android TV main Activity, and finally do manual checks in code. Some of the existing stuff can be re-used on Android TV, and some areas will need to be re-written.

What do you think is the best option?

I personally think that the second option is the best, as it's significantly easier to do, but it does have a few disadvantages, i.e. a larger APK size.

Answer (score 2):

It really goes down to your project, how it is built, how big it is, and so on. In a general sense, each option has its own advantages and disadvantages.

**EXTENDING THE SAME PROJECT**

You can decide to *share your code base and add some TV-specific classes to your existing project*. This allows for a **faster bootstrap** for sure, since you have all the code you need right there. Plus, to the end user, **the Play Store entry will not change**, so you will benefit from the *same ratings*, *downloads*, *visibility* and so on. The downside, in this case, is **the risk of your app becoming monolithic** and thus, harder to handle.

**CREATING A NEW MODULE**

On the other hand, going for a separate project **"forces" you to write common modules**, which (to me) sounds like a good thing. You will have a **longer bootstrap** if your code/project is not modular enough, but **in the long term it will pay off**. Also, the APK of your TV application will benefit too, since **it's going to be smaller**. You will have a **different Play Store entry**, but that could be a downside as well as an upside. Finally, I think it feels refreshing to work on a separate project once in a while, so this is a totally subjective plus :)

---

In my company, we decided to go for a separate project/module. We wanted to modularize some common components, so it felt like the right time to do so. That alone was a good reason for us, and we did not regret it. Also, we had the chance to experiment with a new project structure, which involved using a bus ([Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)) and a job queue ([Path's](https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue)).

All in all, it's up to you and to your project. I will try to add as many other points as I can.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the feedback! :)

Comment: Can't you create multiple APKs aimed to different devices, phones and TVs? You can then upload both APKs to the same entry in the Play store.